# Resolvconf-pull-resolved.path: no such file or directory

Tags: boot, networking, recovery-mode

I am having an issue with connecting to my mobile hotspot from the recovery mode.

The reason I want to connect to the internet in this manner is because my pc somehow, got stuck on the boot menu when I tried installing fuse.

I already saw a way of fixing this issue, however I cant fix the issue due to the fact that I cannot enable networking from the recovery menu.

I get two errors which are 'Resolvconf-pull-resolved.path: no such file or directory' and 'networking.service: no such file or directry'.

This hinders me from solving my issue and I get more errors when I try to use commands such as 'apt install fuse3 gnome-session gdm3' in the root.

Please help as I still need to recover important data from the pc.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.